# Using Sockets to Connect to the Internet (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm learning how to use sockets with the book, Python for Informatics, and am stumped by Assignment 12.1, which asks the reader to

> prompt the user for the URL so it can read any webpage. You can use
>   split('/') to break the URL into its component parts so you can
>   extract the host name for the socket **connect** call. Add error
>   checking using try and except to handle the condition where the user
>   enters an improperly formatted or non-existent URL.

Here is my attempt:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
x = raw_input("Please enter a URL: ")
try:
    mysock.connect((x, 80))
    mysock.send('GET x')
except:
    Print "I'm sorry, but I cannot open this webpage!"
    quit()

While True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1) :
        break
    print data

mysock.close()
```

All I get is "Command Not Found."

Any help would be sooo much appreciated!

Comment: No line number included in the error?

Comment: Please post the complete traceback. I'm not aware of any "Command not found" errors that could be thrown by your code, are you sure you called your program rightly?

Comment: Sadly, no. =( No line was indicated. The program just won't run.

Comment: I assume you ran it in a shell? I get "Command not found" when trying to execute Python scripts with the shell. Either start your program with "python myprogram.py", or put a proper shebang in the first line. Once it runs, there is a *lot* that won't work with this approach, e.g. asking for an URL where you mean (and can only use) a host, not following HTTP protocol and so forth. So I would suggest using e.g. the "requests" library.

Comment: Please also post how you are running your program -- the exact command-line that you are using to call python, OS, etc...

Comment: Oh wait, I forgo to type "Python" before the actual file! Apologies! I'm still getting an error though! I typed "python 12.1.py" and then received the following error:

python: can't open file '12.1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: What's the requests library? How can I use it?

Comment: That means there is no `12.1.py` file to execute. Are you in the right folder? The requests libraby makes it easier to communicate with http servers. I don't think your book wants you to use it yet.

Comment: Hahaha, yeah I don't think my book wants me to use it yet either. ;)

As for the directory,I made sure to move it to the Desktop and that's where I've been this whole time. Not really sure why I get these weird command errors if it's indicating that I'm in the wrong directory. I'm where I'm supposed to be... I think ? O_O

Answer (score 0):

so this is my attempt (withouth the error checking of the URL) and it gives an error as well "Bad Request", "your browser sent a request that this server could not understand".

I assume it has something to do with this particular part: ("GET **fname** HTTP/1.0\n\n)"). Is there anyway to insert the variable "fname" (which the URL prompted from user) here?

```
import socket
fname = raw_input("Enter an URL: ")
parts = fname.split("/")
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect( (parts[2], 80))
mysock.send("GET fname HTTP/1.0\n\n)")
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len (data) < 1) :
        break
print data
mysock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
url = raw_input('Enter url-')
words = url.split('/')
print words
if words[0] != 'http:':
    host_url = words[0]
    url = 'http://'+ url
else:
    host_url = words[2]
request = 'GET '+ url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n'
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((host_url, 80))
mysock.send(request)
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print data
mysock.close()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you posted?

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
url=input('Enter-')
host=url.split('/')[2]
mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((host,80))
cmd=f'GET {url} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
data=mysock.recv(512)
if len(data)<1:
    break
print(data.decode(),end="")
mysock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code, I think it will help you:

```
{import socket

url=input("Enter url >> ")
try:
    address=url.split("/")

    HOST=address[2]

    print("HOST: ",HOST)
    mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect((HOST,80))
    cmd=("GET " + url+ " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").encode()
    mysock.send(cmd)

    while True:
        data=mysock.recv(512)
        if (len(data)<1):
            break
        print(data.decode(), end="")
    mysock.close()    
except:
    print("Improper formatted url")}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked perfectly for me, as the **try** and **except** work in such a way that you are reprompted to enter a web page instead of ending the program altogether:

```
import socket

    while True:
        webpage=input('Enter a web page: ')
        try:
            webpagelst=webpage.split('/')
            host=webpagelst[2]
            mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            mysock.connect((host, 80))
            cmd = 'GET '+webpage+' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
            mysock.send(cmd.encode())
        except:
            print('Please enter a valid web address')
            continue
        while True:
            data = mysock.recv(512)
            if len(data) < 1:
                break
            print(data.decode(),end='')
        break
    mysock.close()
```